# DateTime ToString Converter C# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have converted this piece of code from to VB.net shown bellow this code

```
public class DateTimeToStringConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type type, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string result = "";

        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            DateTime theDate = (DateTime)value;
            result = string.Format("{0:d}", theDate);
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
            result = string.Format("{0:d}", theDate);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type type, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDateTime(value);
    }
}
```

Converted Code

I get an Error 2 **'DateTimeToStringConverter' must implement 'Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, language As String) As Object' for interface 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter'**

```
        Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal type As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal language As String) As Object
        Dim result As String = ""

        If TypeOf value Is Date Then
            Dim theDate As Date = DirectCast(value, Date)
            result = String.Format("{0:d}", theDate)
        Else
            Dim theDate As Date = Date.Now
            result = String.Format("{0:d}", theDate)
        End If

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal type As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal language As String) As Object
        Return System.Convert.ToDateTime(value)
    End Function
```

Can anyone help me out here, Thanks in advance, I appreciated

Comment: Can you copy the entire class, please? You have just copied the Convert function. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Carlos but Behnam provided the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably `implements` keyword is the solution.change your code this way :

```
Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal type As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal language As String) As Object implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim result As String = ""

        If TypeOf value Is Date Then
            Dim theDate As Date = DirectCast(value, Date)
            result = String.Format("{0:d}", theDate)
        Else
            Dim theDate As Date = Date.Now
            result = String.Format("{0:d}", theDate)
        End If

        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Behnam, for interface 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter' it says so there, Thanks a lot